# Is it possible to set up posgresql cron job to invoke supabsae edge function?

Tags: postgresql, curl, cron, supabase

I'm trying to set up CRON job using postresql with supabase edge function. Is it at all possible? This edge function is inserting data to a table and it works properly when invoked using curl. I found out that there is http extension to use GET or POST for posgresql. I'm receiving this error when using this:

```
ERROR:  function http_post(unknown) does not exist
LINE 4:       http_post(
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

this is mine posgresql function:

```
select
  cron.schedule(
    'api-test-insert',
    '15 * * * *',
    $$
    select status
    from
      http_post(
       '<supabase edge function endpoint URL>'
      )
    $$
  );
```

Appreciate any help!

I tried to use POST and GET to achive result. I checked GET method with fake API in posgresql cron job and it returned success with one row from API as expected. I tried GET and POST for edge function and received forementioned error result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining [pg_net](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pgnet) with [pg_cron](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pgcron):

```sql
select
  cron.schedule(
    'invoke-function-every-minute',
    '* * * * *', -- every minute
    $$
    select
      net.http_post(
          url:='https://project-ref.functions.supabase.co/function-name',
          headers:='{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer YOUR_ANON_KEY"}'::jsonb,
          body:=concat('{"time": "', now(), '"}')::jsonb
      ) as request_id;
    $$
  );
```